# jQuery fading page redirect

Tags: jquery, html

I have a working jQuery page redirect. I want to fade into the page I am loading.

```
$(function(){
  var count = 5;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p#redirect").html("You will be redirected in " + count + " seconds");
    if (count == 0) {
      window.location = 'http://link.com';
    }
    if(count < 0) {
        $("p#redirect").html("Please wait...");
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Unless you load the next page in a frame and fade that frame in that's not possible, because as soon as the next page loads, the old javascript code is not active anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with JavaScript, especially if it's another domain.

You can fade content it *from* that page when you get there (the destination page itself doing it), but you can't instruct the browser to do anything at a page it's going *to*, only that page can execute script.

This is mostly due to security reasons, e.g. redirecting you to `https://myBank.com` then running script, well, you see how that could quickly become a problem :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for http://www.jansfreeware.com/articles/ie-page-transitions.html

The problem is it's ***SO*** 1999.
[image]

Comment: Haha, +1 - don't fade pages from one to another - it's frustrating. I'd like to say "some users don't have Javascript enabled" but that is "so 1999" as well :)